# Capture groups with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url string from which I want to capture all the words between the / delimiter:

So given this url:

```
"/way/items/add_items/sell_items":
```

I want to capture:

```
way
items
sell_items
add_items
```

If I do it like this:

```
'/way/items/sell_items/add_items'.match(/(\w+)/g)
=> [ 'way', 'items', 'sell_items', 'add_items' ]
```

It will give me an array back but with no capturing groups, why I do this instead:

```
new RegExp(/(\w+)/g).exec("/way/items/sell_items/add_items")
=> [ 'way', 'way', index: 1, input: '/way/items/sell_items/add_items' ]
```

But this only captures way .. I want it to capture all four words.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `/.../` is already a `RegExp` object.  You don't need to call the constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should write

```
var parts = url.split("/");
```

The `global` flag is used to the `replace` method.
Also, it makes the `exec` method start from the last result (using the `RegExp`'s `lastIndex` property)

Comment: Yes, but be aware that the `/` at the start of the URL results in one empty array element.

Answer (score 4):

If you need by some reasons an exactly Regex, so use this, else use split() function.

**Code:**

```
var re = new RegExp(/\w+?(?=\/|$)/gi);  // added |$
alert(re);
var text = '/way/items/add_items/sell_items';
var aRes = text.match(re);
```

**Result:** [way, items, add_items, sell_items];

Comment: This is PHP, while the question is concerned with JavaScript.

Comment: @jensgram: Thank you!. I changed my post. Javascript supports lookahead operations, but does not support lookbehind.

Comment: But match() doesn't give me captured groups ... just an array with the matches.